# 301 RewriteRule works perfect in OpenLiteSpeed, but only 95% of the time

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301, litespeed

This Wordpress installation previously had a permalink structure of `year/mo/day/post-name` but was later changed to use the post name only. This 301 RewriteRule was added to the top of htaccess, and it works great for the most part, but still fails on several links, leaving the day value in the URL.

```
RewriteRule ([0-9]{4})\/([0-9]{2})\/(.*) domain.com/$3 [R=301,L]
```

I cannot figure out what's causing this, where most redirect to ***domain.com/post-name*** as expected, but a few come back as ***domain.com/08/post-name*** for example.

Is there an issue with the regex that is being overlooked?

Comment: you mean  "domain.com/08/post-name "  does not redirect,  or  "/2020/08/08/post-name"redirected to "/08/post-name" ?

Comment: @qtwrk Sorry, it's the second one. "/2020/08/08/post-name" is redirecting to "/08/post-name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your posts are same format , as in `/2020/01/01/post-name`

then try use

```
RewriteRule ([0-9]{4})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/(.*) https://example.com/$4 [R=301,L]
```

If you have mixed up URL for both `/2020/01/01/post-name` and `/2020/01/post-name`

then try use

```
RewriteRule ([0-9]{4})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/(.*) https://example.com/$4 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ([0-9]{4})\/([0-9]{2})\/(.*) https://example.com/$3 [R=301,L]
```